# Octave kernel is always busy or broken jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, octave, jupyter-lab

so I am trying to set up octave in jupyter lab/note using `conda install -c conda-forge octave_kernel` command from anaconda anddd it works and its downloaded, BUT!!! when I launch jupyter the kernel is always busy and/or disconnects, so I used the command below to check on the kernel as seen.

```
python -m octave_kernel.check
Octave kernel v0.34.2
Metakernel v0.29.0
Python v3.10.4 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2022, 17:32:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python path: C:\Users\\anaconda3\envs\O_R\python.exe

Connecting to Octave...
Octave connection established
octave not found, please see README
```

what does `octave not found, please see README` mean? it already said `Octave connection established`

Answer (score 0):

'please see README' refers to the octave-kernel readme :

https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/blob/master/README.rst

The error is raised in octave_kernel/kernel.py :
if not executable:
raise OSError('octave not found, please see README')

You can try adding OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE = .../bin/octave-cli.exe to your environment variables and reboot.

Gregory